# Site crashes after installing Devel modules with the Theme developer module

Tags: drupal

I have to extend an existing Drupal installation with a few features. I am working on a dump of our live system.

I want to search for a bug and install the above mentioned modules, after the installation some pages of the site are completely empty, except for a picture. Some other pages seams to still work as the whole page did before.

I am using the following versions of Drupal and third-party modules:

- Drupal 6.19
- Devel 6.x-1.24
- Theme Developer 6.x-1.x-dev

Do you have any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the exact problem but add the code below to the top of index.php file so your site will show the exact error. php settings can hide these messages but we are going to show them for debug purposes.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

// $Id: index.php,v 1.94 2007/12/26…
```

Note that the "//$id:" part is from the original file.

You can also try renaming the devel_theme folder to a temporary one to see if it works.
If you can give us some examples of pages(relative path) where you get this error, I think I can give more info.

Also, check watchdog and syslog to see any hidden errors if any.